# C++ Mixed Object Array

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I was reading a tile engine tutorial over http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/tbw/tut02.html but I got stuck when I translate the Flash code into C++ . So far I understand and translate this part:

```
unsigned int MAPDATA[6][8] = {
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
};

class Tile0 {
    public:
        Tile0();
        bool walkable = true;
        unsigned int frame = 0;
};

class Tile1 {
    public:
        Tile1();
        bool walkable = false;
        unsigned int frame = 1;
};
```

But on this line, it saids,

> "First line game.Tile0= function () {} declares new object prototype. When we get 0 from map array, we will use Tile0 as template to make new tile object on that position."

Does it mean converting the array MAPDATA into an object array?

```
unsigned int MAPOBJS[6][8] = {
    { Tile1, Tile1, Tile1, Tile1, Tile1, Tile1, Tile1, Tile1 },
    { Tile1, Tile0, Tile0, Tile0, Tile0, Tile0, Tile0, Tile1 },
    { Tile1, Tile0, Tile1, Tile0, Tile0, Tile0, Tile0, Tile1 },
    { Tile1, Tile0, Tile0, Tile0, Tile0, Tile1, Tile0, Tile1 },
    { Tile1, Tile0, Tile0, Tile0, Tile0, Tile0, Tile0, Tile1 },
    { Tile1, Tile1, Tile1, Tile1, Tile1, Tile1, Tile1, Tile1 }
};
```

Or does it mean indirect reference 0 with Tile0? How do you do that on C++ so later you can...

```
if ( MAPOBJS[1][5].walkable )
    player.moveLeft();
```

for collusion detection?

Comment: You can create an object array, yes, but it must not be of type `unsigned int`, but of the type `Tile *`, which in turn needs to be a superclass to both `Tile0` and `Tile1`. Otherwise it will give you type errors.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium As I know, compiler requires type to determine the size for the data. Tile0 and Tile1 are extend from Tile, and since extend class can be larger than its base class, is it alright for Tile MAPOBJS[] to hold Tile0 and Tile1? Won't that be invalid?

Comment: No, that won't be invalid, as long as you're storing pointers to tile objects. Every pointer has the same size, regardless of the object it points to (integer size, 4 Byte on a 32-bit system). Polymorphism 101: Every child class is also a parent class. So every child class can be cast to a parent class without a problem. This way you can save a lot of memory by only having one object each per tile and simply copying references to these tiles into your array...you'll only have two actual objects, but x tiles with them.

Comment: But the polymorphism will end as soon as one wants to use these objects of the base class as their particular subclasses and calling their specific methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to read original article first.. Well I think whats proposed there can be substitute by something like (don't pretend to be optimised or whatsoever), but I hope it will give you general idea.

```
class Tile {
   public:
     enum {
        TILE0,
        TILE1
     };

     Tile(int type) : m_type(type) {};
   protected:
     int m_type;   
};

class Tile1 : public Tile {
     Tile1( Tile::TILE0 );
};

class Tile2 : public Tile {
     Tile2( Tile::TILE1 );
};

int mapData[6][8] = {
     { Tile::TILE0, Tile::TILE1, ... }, 
     { ... }
};

Tile * mapObject[6][8];


initMap() {
   for (int i=0;i<6;i++) 
     for (int j=0;j<8;j++) {
       switch (mapData[i][j]) {
           case Tile::TILE0:
              mapObect[i][j] = new Tile1();
           break;
           case Tile::TILE1:
              mapObject[i][j] = new Tile2();
           break;
           default:
              mapObject = NULL;
           break;
       }
   }
}
```